# Class method input variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

Often when I create classes in Python (and other languages) I struggle to decide which is a better practice: (a) using instance variables in my method functions, or (b) listing the input variables in the function definition.

(a)

```
    class ClassA(object):
        def __init__(self, a):
            self.variable_a = a

        def square_a(self):
            return self.variable_a ** 2
```

(b)

```
   class ClassB(object):
        def __init__(self, b):
            self.variable_b = b

        def square_b(self, input_var):
            return input_var ** 2
```

These examples are very simple and obvious, but highlight what I find confusing in regard to which is the better idea. Furthermore, is it taboo to set an instance variable outside of the `__init__` method? For example:

```
   class ClassC(object):
        def __init__(self, c):
            self.variable_c = c

        def square_c(self):
            self.square_of_c = self.variable_c ** 2
```

**EDIT**: I understand the somewhat-vague nature of this question, but I asked it because it's difficult to know what people expect to see in source code that I write for, say, collaborative projects. If one or more of the examples I gave is an anti-pattern, my thinking was that this question would provide me with helpful insight.

From PEP 20:

`There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.`

Comment: Depends on your real use case.

Comment: It depends what you want. If you want an ability to perform multiple calculations using different "variable_c" values, than you need a way to pass that value in an object, either directly in the "square_c" method, or using some kind of setter.

Comment: @Alan whilst not the downvoter, it doesn't suggest that at all. The downvote is not intended to reflect on the position of the OP at all, but objectively on the perceived value of the question. Your comment suggests that the OP's circumstances have some role to play in being downvoted. It's exactly that interpretation that makes people feel unwelcome in the first place.

Comment: @roganjosh I stand by my statement, which I base on plenty of experience beyond this one case.  However, I am glad you are concerned to make people feel welcome when they post with a `python` tag. May your concern propagate.

Comment: I did my best to phrase my question(s) in a way that I felt could attract a helpful response and leave behind a helpful discussion for someone else who may wonder about the same semi-unclear facet of the Python language down the road. I quoted the "Zen of Python" in an effort to make clear *why* I asked such a question. There is certainly no need for unhelpful animosity in the comments section. I appreciate **everyone's** insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this example, (b) is not very useful as a member function.  It could just as easily be a free function:

```
def square(input_var):
    return input_var ** 2
```

This is arguably a better interface as it can be used in any context, not just from an instance of `ClassB`.

Generally I would go with (a) if I know `self.variable_a` is the only input the function should need.  If I want it to work with anything and it doesn't depend on anything in the class, I would make it a free function.  If I want it to work with anything but it *does* depend on some class state, then make it a member that takes the input as a parameter.  As an example, what if `ClassA` contained both a `variable_a` and a `variable_b`?  You couldn't use `square_a` to modify `variable_b`, which may or may not be desired depending on the actual use case.

> Furthermore, is it taboo to set an instance variable outside of the **init** method?

No, but it's generally a good idea to make sure all members are initialized somewhere around the time of class instantiation.  Even if you just initialize your members to `None`.  It is much easier to check if a member variable is `None` rather than trying to determine whether or not it is defined.

EDIT: Another few examples:

```
# Here a free function makes the most sense because the operation is 'pure'
# i.e. it has no side effects and requires no state besides its input arguments
def square(value):
    return value ** 2

class LoggedCalculator(object):
    def __init__(self, logger):
        self.__logger = logger

    # (a) makes more sense here because it depends on class state and doesn't need to change
    # its behavior by taking in some parameter
    def get_logger(self):
        return self.__logger

    # (b) makes more sense here because we rely on a mixture of class state and some other input
    def square(self, value):
        result = square(value) # Re-use free function above
        self.__logger.info('{}^2 = {}'.format(value, result))
        return result

calc = LoggedCalculator(logging.getLogger())
calc.square(4)  # This requires an instance of LoggedCalculator
square(2)       # This can be called anywhere, even if you don't have a logger available
```

Comment: So it's not confusing to have methods that have `self` as the only input, even if those methods might use one or more instance (or even class) variables?

Comment: @questionable_code Again, it pretty much depends on your use case.  In your question, I would consider (a) confusing because it is unnecessarily complex.  Why should I have to create a `ClassA` and set its `variable_a` member before I can call `square_a`?  The class doesn't provide any utility.  But there are certainly other cases outside of your example where a method like that *would* make sense.  I've edited my post with a few more examples.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is really vague and therefore difficult to answer. All classes seem to have correct syntax.

However b) looks more useful to me than a)
It looks like you just want to return the square of the input variable, so I'd assume you want to calculate the square of different values all the time. If you do that in case a) you will have to set the variable every time before you call the method.

b) makes me wonder what you use variable_b for as it's never used really. But I guess that's due to simplification.
Also you might consider making square_b a [static method](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#staticmethod), as it doesn't use any object attributes. (never calls `self`)

```
class ClassB(object):
    def __init__(self, b):
        self.variable_b = b

    @staticmethod
    def square_b(input_var):
        return input_var ** 2
```

Variant c) is also valid in terms of syntax, but some might regard it bad practice. A question of taste really, but many books and websites will advise you to declare variables in the **init** method.